# Angular 12 forkJoin deprecated because misinterpreted object type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to call `forkJoin` with a dictionary, taking example from the docs

```
import {
    forkJoin,
    of,
    timer
} from 'rxjs';


/*.....*/


const observable = forkJoin({
    foo: of(1, 2, 3, 4),
    bar: Promise.resolve(8),
    baz: timer(4000),
});
observable.subscribe({
    next: value => console.log(value),
    complete: () => console.log('This is how it ends!'),
});
```

But I'm getting a warning that the method is deprecated. I guess this is because the type of the object I pass to `forkJoin` is interpreted wrong - jumping to declaration shows

```
export function forkJoin<A extends readonly unknown[]>(...sources: [...ObservableInputTuple<A>]): Observable<A>;
```

not the

```
// forkJoin({a, b, c})
export function forkJoin(sourcesObject: { [K in any]: never }): Observable<never>;
export function forkJoin<T extends Record<string, ObservableInput<any>>>(
  sourcesObject: T
): Observable<{ [K in keyof T]: ObservedValueOf<T[K]> }>;
```

The warning
[image: deprecation warning]

Calling a method with array works fine.

How can I fix this?

Libraries used:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.2.0",
    "tslib": "^2.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.3"
  }
```

Comment: maybe your node_modules are not up to date, or IDE's typescript should be updated?

Comment: Just removed `node_modules` directory and reinstalled it and checked typescript version in IDEA, no help(

Comment: anyway, can't reproduce it, so these were 2 my guesses

Comment: @Andrei Do you use the same libraries version as I do?

Comment: yes, tried your package.json

Comment: Thank you, I'll try digging in this way

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to bump a major version in rxjs while they even use 6.x.x https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/12.0.4/package.json#L144

Comment: @eko I migrated to 7.x.x because I thought it would solve the issue, it appears on a 6..x.x too.

Comment: See this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/41897

Comment: @DeborahK I don't get your point, what I should've find there

Comment: It outlines some of the issues of trying to use RxJS 7 with Angular 12. But I see now above that the issue happens with RxJS 6 as well, so it wasn't helpful.